# Toolbar not displayed in my Joomla MVC component

Tags: custom-component, mvc

view.html.php

```
class gezcViewVliegtuigen extends JViewLegacy
{ 
    protected $editID = 0;

     // if task is not specifiek in the url als parameter, display will be used
    function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $context = "com_gezc.list.site.vliegtuigen";

        // aanroep URL
        $uri = JFactory::getURI();
        $this->requestURL = $uri->toString();

        // Assign data to the view
        $this->vliegtuigen = $this->get('Vliegtuigen');
        
        $this->paginas = new JPagination($this->get('Aantal'), $this->get('Start') , $this->get('Limit'));

        $this->state = $this->get('State');
        $this->filter_order     = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($context.'filter_order', 'filter_order');
        $this->filter_order_Dir = $app->getUserStateFromRequest($context.'filter_order_Dir', 'filter_order_Dir', 'asc', 'cmd');
        $this->filterForm       = $this->get('FilterForm');
        $this->activeFilters    = $this->get('ActiveFilters');

        // Check for errors.
        if (count($errors = $this->get('Errors')))
        {
            JLog::add(implode('<br />', $errors), JLog::WARNING, 'jerror');

            return false;
        }

        // Set the toolbar
        $this->addToolBar();

        // Set the document
        $this->setDocument();

        // Display the view
        parent::display($tpl);      
    }
    
    protected function addToolBar()
    {
        JToolbarHelper::title(JText::_('COM_HELLOWORLD_MANAGER_HELLOWORLDS'));  
        JToolbarHelper::addNew('vliegtuigen.add');
    }   

    protected function setDocument() 
    {
        $isNew = true; // ($this->item->id < 1);    TODO
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->setTitle($isNew ? JText::_('COM_GEZC_VLIEGTUIGEN_TITEL_CREATING') :
                JText::_('COM_GEZC_VLIEGTUIGEN_TITEL_EDITING'));
    }
}
```

default.php

```
JHtml::_('behavior.framework', true);

// TODO 
JHtml::script("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.6/dist/js/uikit.min.js");
JHtml::script("https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js");
JHtml::stylesheet('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.4.6/dist/css/uikit.min.css');


$listOrder     = $this->escape($this->filter_order);
$listDirn      = $this->escape($this->filter_order_Dir);
?>
<h1>Vliegtuigen</h1>

<form action="<?php echo $this->requestURL; ?>" method="post" id="adminForm" name="adminForm">
<div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <?php
                echo JLayoutHelper::render(
                    'joomla.searchtools.default',
                    array('view' => $this)
                );
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="uk-overflow-auto">
        <table class="table uk-table-striped uk-table-small uk-table-hover" id="tableX">
            <thead>
....
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
....
            </tfoot>
            <tbody>
....           
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="task" value=""/>
    <input type="hidden" name="boxchecked" value="0"/>  
    <input type="hidden" name="filter_order" value="<?php echo $listOrder; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="filter_order_Dir" value="<?php echo $listDirn; ?>"/>

    <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>  
</form>
```

The table and the search bar is nice displayed. The filter works correctly, but for some reason the toolbar is not displayed.

I tried to check the implementation in Joomla, but there is a lot of magic going on under the hood. Can some explain what I am doing wrong and how it works within de Joomla framework?

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.  Consider giving yourself a more _human_ username and perhaps tell us a little about yourself /your Joomla experience in your profile.

Comment: Odd...I dropped your code into an existing component and the New button appears just fine...

Comment: Is this by chance a frontend view?

Comment: Yes, this is a frontend view. It is located in the site folder within the custom component. Basically the logged in user need to be able to add a record when using the frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toolbar isn't really supported in frontend. In backend it's rendered by `mod_toolbar` module which is only available in backend.

You can still render the toolbar in frontend using this code but it may not necessarily work correctly:

```
echo Joomla\CMS\Toolbar\Toolbar::getInstance('toolbar')->render('toolbar');
```